# Cannot connect to the internet. nslookup outputs “;; communications error to 127.0.0.53#53: timed out”

Tags: linux, networking, dns, routing

After a VPN client stopped responding, I found myself locked out of the internet. I uninstalled the VPN client & removed the VPN entry from gnome-control-center thinking it would fix the issue. But sadly my internet isn't working. Following are the commands I tried after browsing through the internet, I think so there is some issue with the DNS or some networking configuration.

Network interface reveals my wireless interface is `wlp3s0`

```bash
$ ifconfig
```

```
br-113d6b3aff1c: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.21.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.21.255.255
        ether 02:42:e8:6d:c5:3f  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-700caf3b9fcc: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:40:c2:d4:e3  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-b06e3f395e66: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.19.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.19.255.255
        ether 02:42:74:90:1f:cf  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.18.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.18.255.255
        ether 02:42:49:35:3c:fc  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp2s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 98:e7:43:3e:de:fb  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ipv6leakintrf0: flags=195<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::8fe8:e906:5cee:7911  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fdeb:446c:912d:8da::  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether e2:bb:a0:58:54:41  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 680  bytes 69423 (69.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2742  bytes 204246 (204.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2742  bytes 204246 (204.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

pvpnksintrf0: flags=195<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1500
        inet 100.85.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 100.85.0.255
        inet6 fdeb:446c:912d:8da::  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::3c92:cf98:c28d:3a21  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ca:8c:af:5d:b6:0d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3  bytes 126 (126.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

pvpnroutintrf0: flags=195<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1500
        inet 100.85.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 100.85.0.255
        inet6 fdeb:446c:912d:8da::  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::ca86:f224:7976:ebc8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 66:31:57:9b:2a:d0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 690  bytes 69826 (69.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.61.73  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 172.17.63.255
        inet6 fe80::5787:7494:415:36  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether e8:6f:38:cd:58:d7  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 27  bytes 6089 (6.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 73  bytes 8899 (8.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Displaying the routing table shows `172.17.63.254` to be the default gateway for `wlp3s0`

```bash
$ ip route
```

```
0.0.0.0/2 dev pvpnroutintrf0 proto static scope link metric 97 
default via 100.85.0.1 dev pvpnksintrf0 proto static metric 98 
default via 172.17.63.254 dev wlp3s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
64.0.0.0/4 dev pvpnroutintrf0 proto static scope link metric 97 
80.0.0.0/5 dev pvpnroutintrf0 proto static scope link metric 97 
88.0.0.0/8 dev pvpnroutintrf0 proto static scope link metric 97 
89.0.0.0/11 dev pvpnroutintrf0 proto static scope link metric 97 
89.32.0.0/14 dev pvpnroutintrf0 proto static scope link metric 97 
89.36.0.0/15 dev pvpnroutintrf0 proto static scope link metric 97 
89.38.0.0/18 dev pvpnroutintrf0 proto static scope link metric 97 
89.38.64.0/19 dev pvpnroutintrf0 proto static scope link metric 97 
89.38.96.0/23 dev pvpnroutintrf0 proto static scope link metric 97 
89.38.98.0/24 dev pvpnroutintrf0 proto static scope link metric 97 
89.38.99.0/25 dev pvpnroutintrf0 proto static scope link metric 97 
89.38.99.128/27 dev pvpnroutintrf0 proto static scope link metric 97 
89.38.99.160/28 dev pvpnroutintrf0 proto static scope link metric 97 
89.38.99.176/29 dev pvpnroutintrf0 proto static scope link metric 97 
89.38.99.184/30 dev pvpnroutintrf0 proto static scope link metric 97 
89.38.99.189 dev pvpnroutintrf0 proto static scope link metric 97 
89.38.99.190/31 dev pvpnroutintrf0 proto static scope link metric 97 
89.38.99.192/26 dev pvpnroutintrf0 proto static scope link metric 97 
89.38.100.0/22 dev pvpnroutintrf0 proto static scope link metric 97 
89.38.104.0/21 dev pvpnroutintrf0 proto static scope link metric 97 
89.38.112.0/20 dev pvpnroutintrf0 proto static scope link metric 97 
89.38.128.0/17 dev pvpnroutintrf0 proto static scope link metric 97 
89.39.0.0/16 dev pvpnroutintrf0 proto static scope link metric 97 
89.40.0.0/13 dev pvpnroutintrf0 proto static scope link metric 97 
89.48.0.0/12 dev pvpnroutintrf0 proto static scope link metric 97 
89.64.0.0/10 dev pvpnroutintrf0 proto static scope link metric 97 
89.128.0.0/9 dev pvpnroutintrf0 proto static scope link metric 97 
90.0.0.0/7 dev pvpnroutintrf0 proto static scope link metric 97 
92.0.0.0/6 dev pvpnroutintrf0 proto static scope link metric 97 
96.0.0.0/3 dev pvpnroutintrf0 proto static scope link metric 97 
100.85.0.0/24 dev pvpnroutintrf0 proto kernel scope link src 100.85.0.1 metric 97 
100.85.0.0/24 dev pvpnksintrf0 proto kernel scope link src 100.85.0.1 metric 98 
128.0.0.0/1 dev pvpnroutintrf0 proto static scope link metric 97 
169.254.0.0/16 dev pvpnroutintrf0 scope link metric 1000 
172.17.0.0/16 dev br-700caf3b9fcc proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.17.48.0/20 dev wlp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.61.73 metric 600 
172.18.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 linkdown 
172.19.0.0/16 dev br-b06e3f395e66 proto kernel scope link src 172.19.0.1 linkdown 
172.21.0.0/16 dev br-113d6b3aff1c proto kernel scope link src 172.21.0.1 linkdown
```

nslookup google throws an err

```bash
$ nslookup google.com
```

```
;; communications error to 127.0.0.53#53: timed out
;; communications error to 127.0.0.53#53: timed out
;; communications error to 127.0.0.53#53: timed out
;; no servers could be reached
```

However I can successfully ping 127.0.0.53 from my system.

Also pinging to default gateway is successfull

```bash
$ ping 172.17.63
```

```
PING 172.17.63.254 (172.17.63.254) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.17.63.254: icmp_seq=1 ttl=254 time=7.36 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.63.254: icmp_seq=2 ttl=254 time=2.62 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.63.254: icmp_seq=3 ttl=254 time=2.51 ms
```

> `1.1.1.1` is a public recursive DNS resolver operated by Cloudflare. Learn more about this [here](https://www.cloudflare.com/en-in/learning/dns/what-is-dns/). Similarly 8.8.8.8 is google's DNS resolver.
> `127.0.0.53` is the local caching stub resolver which further directs the DNS query to upstream DNS servers

Pinging to `1.1.1.1` fails

```
$ ping 1.1.1.1
```

```
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
262 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 267264ms
```

Similarly ping `8.8.8.8` fails

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8
```

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 5119ms
```

Trying journalctl revealed some warning(?)

```
$ journalctl -u systemd-resolved -f
```

```
Sep 24 14:12:11 the-laptop systemd-resolved[533]: Using degraded feature set UDP instead of TCP for DNS server ::1.
Sep 24 14:12:11 the-laptop systemd-resolved[533]: Using degraded feature set UDP instead of TCP for DNS server ::1.
Sep 24 14:12:21 the-laptop systemd-resolved[533]: Using degraded feature set TCP instead of UDP for DNS server ::1.
Sep 24 14:12:21 the-laptop systemd-resolved[533]: Using degraded feature set TCP instead of UDP for DNS server ::1.
Sep 24 14:12:21 the-laptop systemd-resolved[533]: Using degraded feature set UDP instead of TCP for DNS server ::1.
Sep 24 14:12:21 the-laptop systemd-resolved[533]: Using degraded feature set UDP instead of TCP for DNS server ::1.
^C
```

Tried to get rid of "degraded feature set..." by following [this](https://superuser.com/a/1791986). But I can't still connect to the internet.

Would really appreciate if someone could explain what couldv'e gone wrong & how could I fix this. Thanks!

Comment: Try:   sudo apt-get --fix-missing update  ..... to get missing updates. Thensudo apt-get dist-upgrade .....  to install new dependencies.  Wrap up with:  sudo apt-get update  sudo apt -get upgrade and sudo apt-get autoremove   .....  Restart and test.

Comment: You realize you have two default routes, right?

Comment: @BarryCarter Thanks for pointing that out. I suspect that the VPN client must've left that default route. So I deleted the default route. And now my nslookup is working, i.e nslookup sucessfully resolves google.com. But I still cannot ping it or connect to the internet. 
( I know very little about how these things work, please correct me if I claim something incorrect. Thanks again!)

Comment: Try doing a traceroute to an ip address to see what happens and where it fails. If you can nslookup, you can at least hit your own nameserver

Comment: I made use of `tracepath` since `traceroute` is not installed. The output of the 
`$ tracepath google.com` is 
```
1?:  [LOCALHOST]       pmtu 1500
1: no reply
2: no reply
3: no reply
4: no reply
^C
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> TLDR; I am able to connect to the internet after I permanently removed the network interfaces/devices the VPN client had created.

After I came across [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/624396/remove-network-interface-permanently) discussion, I ran the following command to list down the connections through `nmcli`

```bash
$ nmcli connection show
```

I found out that the VPN client's interfaces/devices were still active (since they were colored green in the terminal output).

So I deleted each of the interface/device which was linked to the VPN client via running the following command(Note: UUID for each device can be found from the show command that we ran previously):

```bash
$ nmcli connection delete <UUID>
```

Post these steps, I was successfully able to connect to the internet. Thanks to [Barry](https://superuser.com/users/1691478/barry-carter) for giving me some direction! I am still learning so please feel free to correct me & it would be great if someone could explain why this issue happened in the first place. Thanks!